# Active Directory: Swap two users' home folders

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

I have an AD domain w/ some users. Each user has a home folder that's on a shared network drive. Due to a silly situation, two users have been using each other's accounts for a long time (including saving stuff in the home folders).

I'm trying to rectify the situation, but I want each user to have the files from the other user. What's the easiest way to swap the home directories without causing massive permission issues?

To clarify: User1 has been logging in as User2. I want User1 to have all the files from User2's profile, and vice-versa.

Comment: First of all, kick them **hard** for using the others account. Then fire them. :)

Comment: Im putting this as a comment, because I havent used it in forever.  I *think* the Windows User State Migration Tool (USMT) will work for you.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10837

Comment: Next, you can simply move the homedirs and reset the rights. This should be simple on a home directory where only the users whose homedir it is has access. (well, possibly the user and the backups software. Nobody else, including the admin, should be able to access files in it).